# I need some help on creating an automation script using Github as my "playground"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been doing a lot of selenium practices lately. However, I haven't been able to create an automation script that would allow me to create a new gist on github. To those of you who are familiar with gist on github, on https://gist.github.com/, there is a big Text Area that would allow the user to type in the code. I've tried using xpath to no avail. I've also made sure that I use the latest version of geckodriver and .jar. Using cssselector also didn't work. From what I've discovered, there are tons of divs on that Text Area. To make things short and simple, how do I create an automation script for that big text area?

[screenshot of https://gist.github.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzUX3.png)

Comment: please show the error u r getting ? see if it is a sync issues, like adding waits etc
share xpaths u have used , also try with cssSelector once

Answer (score 0):

it use CodeMirror text editor, try `executeScript` with the code below

```
document.querySelector('.CodeMirror').CodeMirror.setValue('Hello World!')
```